# Custom Post Type Rewrite Rule

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, slug

My theme uses the following code:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => $this->safe_name . '-detail'),
```

which produces this slug:

```
http://www.example.com/estate-detail/4-bedroom-property-for-sale/
```

I need to get rid of the 'estate-detail' part so I changed the rule to just:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => ' '),
```

This produces the slug as:

```
http://www.example.com//4-bedroom-property-for-sale/
```

How do I get rid of the double forward slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'filterslash_post_type_link', 11, 2);

function filterslash_post_type_link( $post_link, $post ){
    $post_link = home_url("/$post->post_name/");
    return $post_link;
}
```

Comment: will this work only for custom post types? Pages and normal posts do not require any editing.

Comment: to make it work with builtin post - add_filter( 'post_link', 'filterslash_post_type_link', 11, 2);

to make it work with builtin page - add_filter( 'page_link', 'filterslash_post_type_link', 11, 2);

Comment: i also added this to my themes functions.php but it doesn't seem to work... The links still contain the //

Comment: i am using custom post types - not normal posts...

Comment: try using a higher priority. Try Changing 11 to 9999.

Comment: no the link becomes even worse: http://www.domain.com/www.domain.com//4-bedroom-property-for-sale/

Comment: Ok then use this - 

`function filterslash_post_type_link( $post_link, $post ){
    $post_link = home_url("/$post->post_name/");
    return $post_link;
}`

Comment: still the same.. note that when i click on the link i am actually being directed to the post but the link appears erroneously on the home page, category pages, archives etc..

Comment: sorry for some reason it seems to work now! don't know how :) could you please update your answer above and i will tick it as correct..